# Check if string contains a word then perform action

Tags: php, regex, filter

Currently I have a simple swear filter in place with an array of words, I am now also wanting to do checking on strings to see if they contain any:

Here's my list:

```
$words = array(
"/foo/is",
"/bar/is",
"/baz/is"
);
```

So I basically want to search a string for any of those words, if it picks up even one of them, then do something.

Is that easily doable?

Comment: Scunthorpe Problem alert...

Comment: is this a joke? nicely censored @smerny

Comment: Which part of what you're trying to do do you not understand?

Comment: Hah sorry should have thought about putting in dummy words, my bad! @madbreaks, I just don't get how to search through that type of array for single words, then if whatever finds them to do something.

Comment: I learnt some new swear words :P

Comment: You have two tasks: 1) search a string to determine if it contains a substring, and 2) loop over an array, doing "1" for each.  Do you not know how to do either?  If not, you may want to spend some time reading up on PHP.

Comment: My point is because the array is setup to be used in regex with the slashes and the insensitive searching, would that not affect a simple loop?

Comment: Related: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: Why put slashes and regex flags in the array at all?  `if(preg_match("/$foo/is", $str)){ ... }`

Comment: It's already used for a preg_replace, my tests showed it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you mean something like:

```
$words = array(
    "/foo/is",
    "/bar/is",
    "/baz/is"
);

$myWord = 'hello';

foreach($words as $check) {
   if (preg_match($check, $myWord )) {
       // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: This is going to get slow if the "swear dictionary" gets larger in size (which it is, as we're inventing new swear words every day).

Comment: Why include the (identical) RegEx flags w/ every string?

Comment: This seems to work, as for identical regex as my other comment mentioned: It's already used for a preg_replace, my tests showed it didn't work if i wrapped the flags around the array inside the replace.